# PyQt5 error "PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name"

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyqt5, python-sip

I've just built PyQt5 in a pyenv virtualenv with python 3.6.3 on OpenSUSE leap, the build went fine, but when I import

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

I can import PyQt5, but then I cannot use the modules under it

```
>>> import PyQt5
>>> PyQt5.QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'PyQt5' has no attribute 'QtCore'
```

I've read [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3637) that the cause could be another sip on the system for example of a PyQt4 installation, I tried to uninstall PyQt4 from the package manager but it didn't help.

I have no idea what to do, any ideas?

If I install the python3-qt5 package and use the system python it works

Edit:

I had the same problem with PyQt4 on another machine on OpenSUSE Leap 15, the solution was to configure sip with:

```
python configure.py --sip-module PyQt4.sip --no-dist-info --no-tools
```

as stated in the [PyQt4 doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html#downloading-sip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so this was pretty easy actually, as stated in the doc ([PyQt4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html#downloading-sip), [PyQt5](https://pyqt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#downloading-sip)), SIP must be configured with the `--sip-module` option, so for PyQt5 I did:

```
python configure.py --sip-module PyQt5.sip --no-tools
```

and for PyQt4:

```
python configure.py --sip-module PyQt4.sip --no-tools
```

This applies for PyQt >= 4.12.2 and PyQt >= 5.11

EDIT:
PyQt5 now has the so called PyQt-builder, see the [PyQt5 doc](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source)

Comment: I am facing a similar problem. Could you pls explain a bit more about your solution? What is this configure.py file?

Comment: calling `configure.py` is part of the [building process](https://riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source), this applies only if you build PyQt yourself

Comment: I have the same issue but the suggested configuration throws the following error: `python: can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.  Based on a suggestion about this last part I tried to update pip setuptools with `pip install --upgrade setuptools` but it did not help.

Comment: Hm I installed via pip3: pip3 install PyQt5-sip
pip3 install PyQt5   -> How can I configure now?

Comment: Broken link to PyQt5 documentation

Answer (score 1):

So for me the this error occured when I tried to use **pyuic5**.

In my case I just had to activate my virtual_environment and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I had this error for quite a while in my PyQt5 application because I was using two custom libraries (libArcus and libSavitar) that also use SIP to compile Python bindings. This was eventually fixed by making sure that my custom libraries (using a newer SIP version) were imported first, before PyQt5:

https://github.com/Ultimaker/Cura/blob/b20a349b4454d08e34b3c3ea3f537a380e4c7696/cura_app.py#L140-L141

This worked. However when running the application through PyCharm's debugger I still got the same error. Today I figured out that PyCharm has an option to "enable PyQt5 compatibility" with a certain PyQt5 version. Disabling this option under Settings -> Debugger -> PyQt compatible fixed this.

Comment: I always wondered what that option does, activating or deactivating it sometimes fixes things.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application importing both PyQt4 and 5?

I've seen the first error on windows with this:

```
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Executable: D:\Python37\python.exe
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not the case

Answer (score 0):

I downgraded the PyQt5 to 5.7.1 and it worked for me.