# ValueError:PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name with <from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage>

Tags: anaconda, pyqt5, python-3.6, spyder, errno

This is already solved by myself but I put this question for someone else.
I think this kind of problem is better as much as we can.
and there doesn't seem be in SOF.

I updated `spyder`.

```
conda update spyder
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - spyder


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    anaconda-custom            |   py36h363777c_0           9 KB
    spyder-3.3.4               |           py36_0         2.6 MB
    spyder-kernels-0.4.4       |           py36_0          68 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         2.7 MB

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  spyder                                       3.3.3-py36_0 --> 3.3.4-py36_0
  spyder-kernels                               0.4.2-py36_0 --> 0.4.4-py36_0

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  anaconda                                   2019.03-py36_0 --> custom-py36h363777c_0
```

When I tried to boot up `spyder`.
From shortcut icon, no application occurs.
So I write this cmd.

```
 C:\Users\****>spyder
```

---

But I have this error

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 186, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 90, in <module>
    from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets  # analysis:ignore
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

So, I have searched [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693993/pyqt5-error-pycapsule-getpointer-called-with-incorrect-name).

I followed the solution.
But it was not the same problem.

the next problem occurs.

```
python: can't open file 'configure.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

How do I solve it?

---

`Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Feb 21 2019, 18:30:04) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The solution is to downgrade `PyQt5`.

```
pip install PyQt5==5.10.1
Collecting PyQt5==5.10.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/22/67cc2bac6ae2cd3a7eabb2a2e91638b94bdc6e0503747e49670ce44bb5b0/PyQt5-5.10.1-5.10.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win_amd64.whl (81.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81.0MB 187kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: sip<4.20,>=4.19.4 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from PyQt5==5.10.1) (4.19.8)
spyder 3.3.4 requires pyqtwebengine<5.13, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: PyQt5
  Found existing installation: PyQt5 5.12.1
    Uninstalling PyQt5-5.12.1:
      Successfully uninstalled PyQt5-5.12.1
Successfully installed PyQt5-5.10.1
```

This problem occurs because the `PyQt5` I installed is beyond version as the version of `spyder`.

Comment: fantastic! One more thing. After downgrading to PyQt5.10.1 and then launching spyder, it complained about missing PyQtWebEngine. I installed it via 'pip install PyQtWebEngine' and then spyder worked like a champ.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is really wrong because you can't mix the pip and conda PyQt5 packages when using Anconda. This can work if you don't create any other conda environment (sometimes it even fails in that case), but as soon as you do that things will break horribly.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba, can you provide the correct way to fix this then?

Comment: You have to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda because this error is probably caused by installing PyQt5 with pip. Please see the second part of [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) to learn how to do that.