# Problems with Anaconda Navigator (Windows 10)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, spyder

[I FOUND THE ANSWER]

I have problems launching applications from Anaconda. I can only launch the Anaconda Navigator with the command line:

```sh
anaconda-navigator
```

directly in the command prompt from Anaconda (which works). I cannot launch the Anaconda Navigator from the shortcut on my Desktop.

Then when I am in the Anaconda Navigator and try to launch applications I have error messages.

For example when launching Spyder :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 186, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 90, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

And when launching Jupyter Notebook :

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in 
from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in 
from zmq import backend
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in 
reraise(*exc_info)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
raise value
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in 
_ns = select_backend(first)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in 
from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from 'zmq.backend.cython' (C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py)
```

I already reinstalled twice Anaconda. And I tried many command lines to update packages from Anaconda. Example :

```sh
activate root
conda update -n root conda
conda update --all
```

I really don't know what to do, I looked on StackOverflow to see if I could find an answer but I haven't find anything.

Thank you.

Comment: After launching Anaconda Navigator, I also have this that appears in the Anaconda's cmd : C:\Users\ASUS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\api\conda_api.py:1364: YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.
  data = yaml.load(f)
2019-09-28 19:44:47,387 - ERROR download_api._download:234
Invalid url https://www.anaconda.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Webinar20-20Three20Ways20to20Move20your20Data20Science20Projects20to20Production.png

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794101/valueerrorpycapsule-getpointer-called-with-incorrect-name-with-from-pyqt5-qtwe.

Comment: The question says, this is a fresh install of Anaconda, but you `activate root`.  If this is a fresh install and you open the anaconda prompt, you shouldn't need to activate an environment.

Comment: I made it work by changing the path of my Anaconda's Navigator Shortcut and by executing the command line : pip uninstall pyzmq