# Error message when launching Spyder from Anaconda

Tags: python, pyqt, anaconda, spyder

I'm having an issue opening Spyder. I was writing code using PyQt to make a GUI and now my Spyder gives an error and won't open. If anyone knows how to deal with this error, please let me know.

```
objc[6276]: Class RunLoopModeTracker is implemented in both /Users/dwaynesmith/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (0x11a64e110) and /Users/dwaynesmith/opt/anaconda3/lib/libQt5Core.5.9.7.dylib (0x125aeba80). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/dwaynesmith/opt/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/Users/dwaynesmith/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 201, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "/Users/dwaynesmith/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 83, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "/Users/dwaynesmith/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer
```

called with incorrect name

Thanks

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794101/valueerrorpycapsule-getpointer-called-with-incorrect-name-with-from-pyqt5-qtwe

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) The first line of your error message is quite clear and telling. You have two versions of PyQt5 in your environment, and the first one in the error was installed with `pip`. You need to remove that one and the error should be fixed.