# Problems with Spyder in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to start Spyder from Anaconda on a Win10, but get the error below. As a result, Spyder does not launch. The same error arises if I try to launch Spyder from the terminal.

Any ideas on the cause of the error and/or how to solve it? There have been similar questions in the past but the errors were different, that's why I am reposting.

`Versions: Spyder - 3.3.6 Anaconda - 1.9.7 Python - 3.7.4`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 186, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 90, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage

ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794101/valueerrorpycapsule-getpointer-called-with-incorrect-name-with-from-pyqt5-qtwe. Not sure if this will resolve it but it's very likely the same issue. try downgrading the package

Comment: Thanks, use the instruction:
conda update --all
Problem solved