# Spyder unable to launch from Anaconda or in stand-alone mode

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

After installing several python packages, I get following error when trying to launch Spyder from Anaconda. Not sure what I messed up during package install, but unable to remove it from Anaconda to install it back. Have tried --reset command as well to no avail.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 233, in main
from spyder.app import mainwindow
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 59, in 
from qtpy import QtWebEngineWidgets # analysis:ignore
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\QtWebEngineWidgets.py", line 22, in 
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEnginePage
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

Let me know how to fix the error so I that Spyder can be launched again from Anaconda without any errors.

Comment: This question may have been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55794101/valueerrorpycapsule-getpointer-called-with-incorrect-name-with-from-pyqt5-qtwe

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) After installing those packages you said (probably using pip), you broke Spyder and now you have to reinstall Anaconda. Please do that by following the instructions in the second part of our [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) about that.